# Entity framework error "Invaid column name" while update record after renaming table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I am using asp.net 4.5 with EF to add/update/delete record.

I renamed a database table StatusMaster to Status.

To reflect this change in entity, I have used "update model from database" in which I have deleted the table first.

Then I have deleted the table from the diagram using "Delete Model".

Then I added table to the edmx file using "Update Model from Database".

I also have update related code in application.

Now Add() method is working well but while update method it gives me error "Invalid column name 'Id'". This column was the primary key before I update but I have also renamed it to "StatusId" but I don't think it should affect it because I already have deleted and added the table using "Update model from database".

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

All the more reason I prefer code first. More work to set up but easier to make changes down the line. Ill suggest you do the following.

- Delete the entire EDMX
- Delete Connection Details from config section in Web.config
- Re-Create EDMX

I discovered that is faster that trying to debug ur relationship in the EDMX diagram